# disable jQuery DatePicker dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, calendar, datepicker

I have attempted to enable selection of only the *first date of each month* in a jQuery datepicker. The possible dates are listed in `var enabledates`.

```
var enabledDays = ["6-1-2013", "7-1-2013", "8-1-2013", 
                   "9-1-2013", "10-1-2013", "11-1-2013"];
function nationalDays(date) {
    var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
    for (i = 0; i < enabledDays.length; i++) {
        if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y, enabledDays) != -1 
            || new Date() > date) {         
            return [true];
        }
    }
    return [false];
}

$(function(){
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.extend($.datepicker.regional["ru"]));
    $("#datepicker1, #datepicker2, #datepicker3").datepicker({
                                                    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                                                    duration: "normal",
                                                    numberOfMonths: [ 1, 2 ],
                                                    constrainInput: true,
                                                    beforeShowDay: nationalDays
                                                });
});
```

How can I apply this first date constraint to the whole calendar?

Comment: maybe you could get something from this. http://jsfiddle.net/HP7A8/

Comment: Could you help me to add to this region language??

Comment: Start a separate question for that, since it's off-topic

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to enable a range I would say you can use the Option properties minDate an maxDate.

Regarding your Problem to enable all Dates from an array. Please have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uYe9X/

```
function available(date) {
  var dt= date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
  if (availableDates.indexOf(dt) !== -1) {
    return [true, "","available"];
  } else {
    return [false,"","not available"];
  }
}
```

As Pedro mentioned you could use the beforeShowDay Callback to reference a function which computes if the day should be enabled. The callback is used for every day which is displayed in the datepicker.
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay